# NSURLSession / NSURLRequestNetworkServiceType - disable tcp buffering / caching (nagle algorithm)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, networking, tcp

for a network live voice communication over http I need to disable every caching and buffering algorithms in a `NSURLSession` on iOS (Objective-C).

I've seen that in a NSURLSessionConfiguration object, i can set the **`networkServiceType`** property (*`NSURLRequestNetworkServiceType`*) to **`NSURLNetworkServiceTypeVoice`**.

Apple's documentation says for **`networkServiceType`**:

> The network service type provides a hint to the operating system about
>   what the underlying traffic is used for. This hint enhances the
>   system's ability to prioritize traffic, determine how quickly it needs
>   to wake up the cellular or Wi-Fi radio, and so on. By providing
>   accurate information, you improve the ability of the system to
>   optimally balance battery life, performance, and other considerations.

and for **`NSURLNetworkServiceTypeVoice`**

> Specifies that the request is for voice traffic.

But it's not clear, if tcp buffering like the nagle algorithm is disabled for voice or not.

PS: I need a solution for iOS7+.

Comment: The `NSURLSession` classes don't seem like the natural choice for voice comms.  Why did you chose them?

Comment: Beacuse I need digest authentication and NSURLSession already implements that.
Currenlty I use a Socket, but here I need to implement digest authentication by myself.